# configurations.compile is empty

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been using the following task to copy libraries:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'cleanLibs') {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

But with newer version of gradle, the compile configuration was replaced with implementation. I think this is why the configurations.compile list is now empty. I've tried referencing `configuration.implementation` and `configuration.implementation.resolvedConfiguration` directly, but this produces the following error:

```
Resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed
```

If I try to use `configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration` I get `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration@5bb68e71`.

How can I achieve the expected result (copy all dependencies to 'libs' folder)?

Comment: This worked for me in a non-android project, YMMV: `from configurations.libs.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.file` (replace libs by the configuration)

Comment: I tried using compile, which is still empty, while using implementation produces the same error

Comment: Seems that Google did something strange in their android gradle plugin ...

Answer (score 2):

Try `configurations.compileClasspath` instead.

This worked for me with Gradle 4.5.1:

```
task listJars {
    doLast {
        configurations.compileClasspath.each { println it }
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in `Could not get unknown property 'compileClasspath' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.`

Comment: Worked for gradle 4.10.1 and Kotlin.js project